# Can I substitute Hong Kong curry cuttlefish with pre-cooked Joya octopus?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

I want make Hong Kong cuisine Dim Sum  [Curry Cuttlefish](https://www.openrice.com/en/hongkong/p-curry-cuttlefish-house-of-canton-p1117846) at home.

[image]

Because COVID19, my supermarket is not selling cuttlefish or squid or uncooked octopus, just this pre-cooked [Joya Octopus](https://www.loblaws.ca/Food/Frozen/Fish-%26-Seafood/Boxed-%26-Bagged-Fillets/Un-Branded-Joya-Octopus-3-Tentacles/p/21154610_EA).

My issue is octopus is much bigger. Thus how substitute Cuttlefish with Octopus? Will this  Joya octopus work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, please try it and report back.

When using precooked octopus, you need to cut them in small bite size pieces and add them to the curry at the last moment so they get up to proper temperature and soak up the flavors of the curry.

Remember that when substituing ingredients, the original recipe might not taste or feel the same as the original recipe.

**Next time, please link to a recipe**; it'll make answering easier.

Comment: Hi! I'm reporting back, but either I botched something or Joya octopuses taste so yucky! I cut Joya octopuses "in small bite size pieces", but they taste like wood and rubber! Way worse than cuttle fish. Do you know why?